# How add locale support to google_map_location_picker ? (Flutter)

Tags: google-maps, flutter, localization, google-maps-android-api-2, flutter-dependencies

How can I add support for "ru" and "kz" Locale in Flutter google_map_location_picker plugin? I tried  this

```
MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        // ... app-specific localization delegate[s] here
        location_picker.S.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      locale: const Locale('ru'),
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('ru'),
        const Locale('en'),
        const Locale('kz')
      ]
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work on iOS, adding the following lines to your `Info.plist` file might help.

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
    <string>ru</string>
    <string>en</string>
    <string>kz</string>
</array>
```